# Escoger el valor más cercano en resultado con decimales

Tags: javascript, mysql, buscador

Tengo un problema en mostrar el valor más cercano como resultado de una búsqueda en decimales. Estoy haciendo un formulario que al agregar un número en decimales me muestre en otro input el valor más cercano de este, por ejemplo:

agrego en un input : 34.67

pero en la base tengo valores fijos tipo así:

```
34.50 ---- 1000
       ----------34.67 // valor del input
34.75 ---- 1120
```

Como puedo hacer para que cuando agregue ese número, mediante el javascript haga la consulta y me muestre el valor más cercano?

Se tendría que hacer en el `WHERE` con un `BETWEEN` o con un `LIKE` ??

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT numero FROM TABLA WHERE decimal LIKE term
```

o

```
SELECT numero FROM TABLA WHERE decimal BETWEEN numero AND numero
```

Comment: Los valores de la base de datos tienen siempre el mismo intervalo? 0.25? O estan al azar?

Comment: @alanfcm tienen el mismo intervalo, de 0.25, 0.50, 0.75...

Comment: Estas usando PHP?

Comment: si, mysql + pdo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay más de una manera de hacerlo, una sería

```
SELECT ABS($valorIngresado - dbDecimal) as Cercano, ...
FROM tuTabla
ORDER BY Cercano ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Otra posibilidad, podría ser esta, pero tendrías un performance un poco inferior

```
SELECT * 
FROM tuTabla
ORDER BY abs(dbDecimal- $valorIngresado)
LIMIT 1
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad, saludos!

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias!